# Houzez Theme removes wp-admin access to all Wordpress user roles

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-login

**While the title says "all" Wordpress user roles, it actually works fine with the Admin role.

I have been testing with Editor and Agent roles, Editor being a default Wordpress user role while agent is theme specific. Neither role can access the wp-admin tab.

The screen shows: "You don't have permission to access this page."
[wp-admin error: You don't have permission to access this page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmRGA.png)

I have been trying to troubleshoot this error and getting it to work. To identify that the Houzez theme is the problem, I followed step 4 of this guide: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-sorry-you-are-not-allowed-to-access-this-page-error-in-wordpress/#aioseo-activating-the-default-theme-using-ftp

Currently I am looking for any known solution to this problem. I have googled around for a while with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted support for the Houzez tool. I had overlooked an option in the Theme Options general settings that restricts access to the admin panel. I just had to switch it off.
[Picture of button to block user admin access.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T82KG.png)